# Intellij debugger frames tab colours / theme

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

The Intellij IDEA CE debugger has a tab named "Frames", showing all stack frames when a breakpoint is hit.
Unfortunately in the "bright" theme the colours make it hard to read. It uses light yellow background and light grey foreground.
Is there a way to customise this please?

[image]

Comment: Frame tab colors are taken from the IDE [Appearance](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/appearance.html) scheme and are not customizable. Btw, related request: [IDEABKL-3010](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-3010).

Comment: @Andrey Thanks for that info - is the answer that this is not possible?

Comment: As @Egor answered you can customize the file backgroung colors but not foreground.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the file backgroung colors in Settings | Appearance & Behavior | File Colors, foreground color is not yet customizable.

Comment: I dont think this is a "File Color"

Comment: Don't you have light yellow in file colors?

Comment: This is the right answer. And, indeed, it's the color used for files outside the project where the stack frames are pointing to.